# xml file doesnt show when app is running for some reason

Tags: java, android, xml

Hi when i run my application for some reason it doesnt run my xml file in the application theres no error or anything but the xml doesnt show.

What the app looks like when it runs (missing home_items xml): https://gyazo.com/1f701b1790f6688d7242eaa5774a3dae

What the home_items looks like: https://gyazo.com/d697abdcd5a4c3d3b2064729fcaa9274

home_items.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/profileImage"
        android:layout_width="56dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_person"
        app:civ_border_color="#434343"
        app:civ_border_width="1dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/profileImage"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nameTv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Username"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/timeTv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="2h"
            android:textColor="#000" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="220dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/profileImage"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/likeBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_heart" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/commentBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_comment" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/shareBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_share" />


    </LinearLayout>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/descTv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:paddingStart="8dp"
        android:paddingEnd="8dp"
        android:text="Description"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/likeCountTv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/descTv"
        android:paddingStart="8dp"
        android:paddingEnd="8dp"
        android:text="100 likes"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

HomeAdapter.java

```
package com.example.soulforge.adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.example.soulforge.R;
import com.example.soulforge.fragments.Home;
import com.example.soulforge.model.HomeModel;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;


public class HomeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HomeAdapter.HomeHolder>{

    private List<HomeModel> list;
    Context context;

    public HomeAdapter(List<HomeModel> list, Context context) {
        this.list = list;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public HomeHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.home_items,parent, false);
        return new HomeHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull HomeHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.userNameTv.setText(list.get(position).getUserName());
        holder.timeTv.setText(""+list.get(position).getTimestamp());


        int count = list.get(position).getLikeCount();
        if(count ==0){
            holder.likeCountTv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }else if (count == 1){
            holder.likeCountTv.setText(count + " like");
        }else{
            holder.likeCountTv.setText(count + " likes");
        }

        holder.descriptionTv.setText(list.get(position).getDescription());


        Random random = new Random();

        int color = Color.argb(255, random.nextInt(256), random.nextInt(256), random.nextInt(256));

        Glide.with(context.getApplicationContext())
                .load(list.get(position).getProfileImage())
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_person)
                .timeout(6500)
                .into(holder.profileImage);

        Glide.with(context.getApplicationContext())
                .load(list.get(position).getImageUrl())
                .placeholder(new ColorDrawable(color))
                .timeout(7000)
                .into(holder.imageView);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return list.size();
    }

    static class HomeHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        private CircleImageView profileImage;
        private TextView userNameTv, timeTv, likeCountTv, descriptionTv;
        private ImageView imageView;
        private ImageButton likeBtn, commentBtn, shareBtn;

        public HomeHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            profileImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.profileImage);
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            userNameTv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameTv);
            timeTv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.timeTv);
            likeCountTv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.likeCountTv);
            likeBtn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.likeBtn);
            commentBtn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.commentBtn);
            shareBtn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.shareBtn);
            descriptionTv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.descTv);


        }
    }
}
```

Hi im wondering whats the issue and why the home_items doesnt show in my application.

Answer (score 0):

Go to
File -> Invalidate Caches/ Restart -> Invalidate and restart

It fixes minor xml bugs

If not,
Post more of your adapter code

---

Updated:
Try adding this to your adapter:

```
@Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }
```

---

Updated:
Try this again in adapter:
in your onCreateViewHolder:

```
return new HomeAdapter.HomeHolder(view);
```

Comment: Hi it didnt fix the issue yet but i have uploaded the whole adapter code for you

Comment: Are you setting the adapter to your recyclerview?
Eg: `recyclervew.setAdapter(homeAdapter);`

Comment: yes `        adapter = new HomeAdapter(list, getContext());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);`

Comment: Check Updated Answer

Comment: Still nothing sadly :(

Comment: Check Updated Answer

Comment: Still doesnt work sadly still just a fragment_home.xml

Answer (score 0):

build -> clean project
then
build -> Rebuild project
then Run

Comment: Tried but didnt change anything sorry